# I'm using breezometer api and leaflet and openstreetmap to show heatmap of world but the api require key and I don't want to show the key to end user

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, leaflet, openstreetmap

I'm creating a project in laravel to show heatmap of a country by using breezometer heatmap layer api and leaflet with openstreet map to achieve the same. But Idk how can I hide the api key from end user as the api url provided does not returning anything in response but working directly in tilelayer function of leaflet. Please tell me is there any way to do the same without exposing the key?

Here is the code that working fine on frontend:
`your text`
let map = L.map('map').setView([28.7041, 77.1025], 13);

L.tileLayer('https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
maxZoom: 19,
attribution: '© [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright)'
}).addTo(map);

L.tileLayer(`https://tiles.breezometer.com/v1/air-quality/breezometer-aqi/current-conditions/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key=${API_KEY}`, {
tms: false,
opacity: 0.65,
maxNativeZoom: 19
}).addTo(map);

I tried calling the function using route in tilelayer method of leaflet.

This is the function I created in my laravel controller but it doesn't worked.
`your text`

public function getTileData() {

```
    $path = 'https://tiles.breezometer.com/v1/air-quality/breezometer-aqi/current-conditions/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?key=685ce23260d0444c90871220f3a8cae6';
    
    $file = Http::withHeaders(['Content-Type' => 'image/png'])->get($path);


    echo $file;
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of the key? Is it a unique dedicated key?

Comment: the key is provided by breezometer and they already mentioned that anyone having the key can access your account

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know laravel, so this is going to be a general idea:

i´m assuming that you have a PHP Server.

You need to create a "proxy" controller. This controller will forward requests adding the secret key to the url at server side time. After this the URL will become something like:

```
L.tileLayer("https://my_laravel_host.com/proxy.php?r=https://tiles.breezometer.com/v1/air-quality/breezometer-aqi/current-conditions/{z}/{x}/{y}.png")
```

This Proxy Controller/Class is going to read the $_GET parameters and request  the .png itself, adding the secret key. After getting the image, just return it to the user.

Look at this old proxy code to see what i mean:
https://github.com/Esri/resource-proxy/tree/master/PHP

You don´t even need to include the full breezometer url. You can let the controller do this. Something like:

```
L.tileLayer("https://my_laravel_host.com/proxy.php?tile=breezometer&style=current-conditions/{z}/{x}/{y}.png")
```

Next step will be to allow only users of your app/site to access this URL.

The downside to this approach is the overhead/costs of requesting your server every time a tile needs to load.

Comment: I tested the api on thunderclient but the problem is api is not returning any response just showing bad request but working fine when using the url in tilelayer function.

Comment: The API, you mean the breezometer? If so, maybe it checks if the request comes from a browser. You probably need to add the same headers a browser adds when requesting the tiles.